# Multipling matricies in assembly

Tags: assembly, matrix, easy68k

This is using easy68K. Hi, I am multiplying two matrices together. I declare constants in a linear fashion at the bottom of the code.But basically I have two matrices, 2 x 2. I am saving in matrix D which has a defined storage. And into the second loop when I go up an address, I get an error:

> Address Error: Instruction at 1028 accessing address 1063 Execution
>   halted

Here is an image:

http://i1107.photobucket.com/albums/h385/Nazariy1995/Problem.png

Here is my code:

```
r   EQU     2   ;number of rows
c   EQU     2   ;number of columns
    ORG    $1000
START:  MOVEA.L     #A,A0
        MOVEA.L     #B,A1
        MOVEA.L     #D,A2

        MOVE.W      #r,D3   ;used for rows
        CLR.W       D0  ;offset for A
        CLR.W       D1  ;offset for B
        CLR.W       D2  ;offset for D
        CLR.W       D5  ;calculating the sum
        CLR.W       D6  ;calculaing the multiplication
        CLR.W       D7  ;used for number of repeats
L2      MOVE.W      #c,D4   ;used for columns mainly for first matrix 
L1      CLR.W       D5
        MOVE.W      (A0,D0.W),D5
        MULU        (A1,D1.W),D5
        ADD.W       D5,D6
        ADD.W       #1,D0
        ADD.W       #c,D1   ;we are moving down a column and thus are adding column to the offset in B
        SUB.W       #1,D4
        BNE         L1
        MOVE.W      D6,(A2,D2.W)
        ADD.W       #1,D2   ;increment counter for C
        ADD.W       #1,D7   ;increment repeat
        CMP.W       #c,D7   ;number of repeats  should be equal to column number
        BNE         RE
        CLR.W       D7      ;clear repeats because we are moving on to a new row
        CLR.W       D1      ;set offset for B to 0
        SUB.W       #1,D3   ;find out through how many rows we went through
        BNE         L2
        STOP        #$2700

RE      SUB.W      #c,D0    ;got at the beginning of a row in A
        MOVE.W      D7,D1
        CLR.W       D6
        BSR        L2

* Put program code here

    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

* Put variables and constants here
A   DC.W    1,2,0,1
B   DC.W    1,0,2,1
D   DS.W    4

    END    START        ; last line of source
```

Please help! I know a little about assembly, and it's just difficult.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have the tool, use it to single step your code and see how it ends up with the incorrect address. Check that each instruction is doing what you want.

Comment: I did I went through it step by step, with step over, I am just not understanding how is it that and address can be wrong. Maybe my displacement is wrong, in terms of word, or by or long word ?

Comment: A word is 2 bytes, and addresses use bytes. Thus, you need to increment your pointers by 2.

Comment: (A0, D0.w*2) is, I believe, the syntax to increase the scale of an index. As it is, you are incrementing by 1 and then trying to access a Word from an odd numbered location. Remember that words must be 2-byte aligned and longs, 4-byte. (You might also want to look at the addq instruction).

Comment: Thank you everyone! Mike and Jester you guys are correct. That it what fixed my program. Funny, my teacher couldn't even find the problem. So Thank you so much!